# Using <strong> for introductory paragraph to a post - a bad idea?

Tags: seo, css

I have a news website and on most posts the first paragraph is in bold. Currently the authors are just using `<strong>` to bold the paragraph, would it be better from an SEO point of view to rather use a paragraph class that is styled with `p.bold {font-weight:bold;}` `<p class="bold">`.

Does `<strong>` on the first paragraph send the wrong message to search engines? The text is important but the main reason it is in bold is because it is the opening paragraph. I realise `<strong>` is used to emphasise certain words on a page

Comment: I've just checked a mayor tech site, they bold it via css and a class. I have no clue wether it actually matters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There does not seem to be any evidence on search engines caring about `strong` markup at all. And they care even less about classes `font-weight` settings.

But in principle, it is possible that some search engines treat `strong` content as more important than normal text, i.e. give it greater relative weight inside a page. But it’s difficult to say what they could do with that information.

So it most probably doesn’t matter to SEO. On general grounds, it is better to use just styling when no particular importance is intended. Usually bolding an entire paragraph is not a good idea. Increased font size or special background color (with CSS) might work better.

Comment: Google generally ignores markup such as bold and strong and others though not completely. It does not effect SEO! There is no additional weight applied to this type of text. None whatsoever. Please do not over think SEO. The mechanics of SEO is far simpler than the various SEO experts lead you to believe. One issue, however, specially marked content can get picked up as the SERP snippet. In that way, it can indirectly effect SEO.

Comment: Search engines definitely *do* take note of strong tags, as evidenced by this Matt Cutts video: http://youtube.com/watch?v=awto_wCeOJ4 However their weight is unlikely to be as much as it used to be.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat. the video talks about the difference between `b` and `strong` and claims that there is none in Google. No evidence is given, and there is no hint of what those tags might matter—what Google would actually do with them. It’s really just usual chat about “semantics” except that it says it does not really matter.

Comment: @Jukka since Google has code that parses b/strong tags specifically, *something* must be done with them. It may be very little, but the fact that video exists (and the original, which doesn't seem to be online any more) proves they do take them into account.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat, Google needs to parse all HTML tags in order to be able to extract the text content, distinguishing them from HTML markup. No evidence has been presented on Google doing anything with `strong` tags but ignore them. Besides, even if it did something with them, this information would be useless if we don’t know anything about *what* it does with them.

Comment: @Jukka You don't need to have code to target every specific HTML element, just the pattern of `<abc>`. Google doesn't have code to specifically parse `<abc>` but it does for `<b>` and `<strong>`.